# MacBook won't connect to the internet via airport or ethernet

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, connection

My MacBook won't connect to the internet at all. Not via airport or via ethernet. Both my other computers - running XP and Vista connect without a hitch everytime but my MacBook refuses to.

When I try to connect via airport it won't get an IP address and via ethernet it gets a self assigned IP. However, when I boot up to my windows 7 via bootcamp then I can connect to the network just fine, so it isn't a hardware issue.

However, if I take it to any of my client's offices then it connects fine, so I'm doubly confused as to why it's only my network/router that has an issue

Apple tech support suggested interference but it doesn't work on any other channel - and I'm confused as to why ONLY Mac OS X has an issue.

I'm running Snow Leopard

Comment: When did it last work ok on your network, if ever? If so, what has changed since then?

Comment: It worked up until a week ago. Nothing has changed in the set up at all and all the PCs work just fine.

The only variable that could have changed is if a neighbour moved in and their wireless network is interfering with mine. But that doesn't explain why I can't connect via ethernet

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the configuration on your DHCP server? If it is working OK on other networks, chances are there is something in your DHCP setup that has it throw a wobbly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I've looked at the router - reset it and still nothing. My macbook also won't connect via ethernet so it's not a router issue, and as I say all my PCs work fine

Comment: I don't think it's an issue that is likely to be cured by a router reset (assuming you're using the router's DHCP server). I'd try to give the MacBook a static IP address first to see if that's working, then have a google for <your router> + DHCP to see if there are any known problems.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any 3rd party firewall running under OS X?

I use NoobProof to control OS X's ipfw firewall and, originally, I didn't have it set up correctly - it was blocking the system services ports (53, 67, 68, 123 and 5353).  One of these is what OS X uses (at least on the wireless side with some access points) to negotiate for an IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've even turned the firewall off and that still hasn't helped. Really regretting buying a mac!

Comment: By 'turned the firewall off' are you referring to OS X's firewall through the System Preferences panel or are you referring to turn off some other program (that might be controlling the ipfw)?  If it's the latter, you still need to flush the pipes.  Otherwise, the rules could still be active.